# Based on one keyword , I send requests to two different sites. But I am able to access only of the response's rootobject

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I am working on a keyword search that looks for a part in two different sites. I have their api and I do get the response.The two responses have different JSONs and different variables in RootObject.
This causes the error

```
 namespace OctopartApi
{
    using Newtonsoft.Json;
    using RestSharp;
    using System;
    using System.Collections;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using UnityEngine;
    using UnityEngine;
    using System.Net;
    using UnityEngine.UI;
    public  class KeywordSearch1 : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public InputField mainInputField;
        public Canvas can;
        public float x, y;
        void Start () {
            mainInputField.onEndEdit.AddListener(delegate {LockInput(mainInputField); });

        }
        void LockInput(InputField input)
        {
            ExecuteSearch (input.text);
        }
        public  void ExecuteSearch(string inp)
        {
            // -- your search query --
            string query = inp;

            string octopartUrlBase = "http://octopart.com/api/v3";
            string octopartUrlEndpoint = "parts/search";
            string apiKey = "57af648b";

            // Create the search request

            var client = new RestClient(octopartUrlBase);
            var req = new RestRequest(octopartUrlEndpoint, Method.GET)
                        .AddParameter("apikey", apiKey)
                        .AddParameter("q", query)
                        .AddParameter("start", "0")
                        .AddParameter("limit", "10");

            // Perform the search and obtain results
            var resp = client.Execute(req);
            string octojson = resp.Content;
            RootOb hh = JsonUtility.FromJson<RootOb> (octojson);// RootOb NOT FOUND ( but Root is recognized)
            Manufacturer manufacturer = hh.manufacturer;//NOT FOUND 

        }


        // -- your API key -- (https://octopart.com/api/register)
        private const string APIKEY = "57af648b";
    }


}
```

This is my model class

```
[System.Serializable]
public class RootOb
{
    public string __class__;
    public Brand brand;
    public Manufacturer manufacturer;
    public string mpn;
    public string octopart_url;
    public List<Offer> offers;
    public List<string> redirected_uids;
    public string uid;
}
```

How I access the response in the second class

```
Root res = JsonUtility.FromJson<Root>(jsonString);//No issues here
```

For some reason , I am able to access only Root and not RootOb.What am I doing wrong ?
The type or namespace name `RootOb' could not be found. Are you missing an assembly reference?

Edit : I tried deleting the Root class,and now RootOb gets detected! Should there be only one def of JsonUtility?

Comment: You do have to put the code that's causing the error

Comment: @Programmer, Hi , me again :) . I just have one question. how do i access deeply nested ones from rootobject. Root object has a list class.. inside which there exists another list class inside which i have a value "packaging". RootObj { public class List<Results> res;}  Results { public class item ;}  Item { public class List<Offers> offers ;}  Offers { string packaging ; }. I want to access packaging.

Comment: I do suggest you post new question for this with your code and the class you want to access. Just make sure to post everything required to answer the question.